# Trying to display a UIImage captured from one viewController, and display it in another in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, xib

I have an iPad application that I am working on where, from my main viewController (call it mainViewController), I call and display another viewController (call it nextViewController) that is created from an .xib file.  This second viewController allows the user to capture an image like so:

```
- (IBAction)imageCapture:(id)sender {

    _myImage = [_nextView captureImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_myImage, nil, nil, nil);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Once this image is captured, I need this image to now be passed back to the calling viewController (mainViewController), but I honestly am not sure how to do this.  I have tried to create a property reference of my mainViewController in my nextViewController, which I was trying to do in order to pass the reference of the newly acquired image to an attribute of the mainController, but this is not working.

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: you can pass this value through protocol. how you tried it with protokol ?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Have you looked at making it a delegate relationship?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies.  I am trying to figure out how to do this using protocols, but this is new to me.  I know theoretically what protocols are, but in this situation, I need an example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this effectively, you should *not* make a property `mainViewController` in the presented view controller. This would cause reusability issues, plus it's tight coupling which is not desirable. Instead, as the comments above note, you should use a protocol. For Objective-C, see [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) for protocol syntax.

In your NextViewController, you should make a delegate method something like this:

```
-(void)nextViewController:(NextViewController *)nextViewController capturedImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

Then, in your main view controller class, you should implement this method and do whatever you want with the image. Notably, you may want to dismiss the controller from the main view controller. Don't forget to set the delegate property of the next view controller when you create it.

I hope this clarifies your problem!

Comment: I would have the delegate method return a `UIImage`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  When I use your line for my protocol declaration:  -(void)nextViewController:(NextViewController *)nextViewController capturedImage:(UIImage *)image; 

I get the following error:



expecting type, with respect to (NextViewController *)  Any reason why this is?

Comment: Yes, I've had that error in this situation. It means you need to move your protocol section past the @interface in the header file, and you need to add a line `@protocol NextViewControllerDelegate;` in the place where the protocol originally was. It's basically a declaration issue, it means the class hadn't been declared yet when you used it.

Comment: @MarcusAdams The reason I used a void return value instead of an image is that the main view controller wants the image, not the next view controller. Since the protocol method is run by the main controller, it shouldn't be passing back an image.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should create a property in `secondViewController` to pass your `mainViewController` to before present the secondViewController. Ex:

```
_secondViewController.mainViewController = self;
```

Secondly, you will need a property in `mainViewController` to pass the image back from `secondViewController`. Ex:

```
self.mainViewController.capturedImage = _myImage;
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I think I would just pass the image, not the controller.